# how to model plane with a lot of vertices

Tags: modeling

[image]

What is the fastest and most useful way of modeling a street with cad layer with a lot of vertices that are not symmetrical on both sides?

Answer (score 4):

**LoopTools** add-on has a few operators that you might find useful, particularly **bridge** or **loft**:

[image]

Above you can see how I make sure all curves have the same number of vertices - had to subdivide one curve and remove 2 excess vertices, then *Relax* it to make it smooth and equalize *Space* between vertices for the best effect of the *Loft*.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to solve the T intersection seen in the picture?

Comment: Probably something like this: https://i.imgur.com/z3k7DcB.png the blue area could be just one quad.